# Mysql - Get records satisfying all values in an array

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a table with fields

```
id  job_id  skill_id
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    1         3
4    2         1
5    3         1
6    3         2 
7    3         3
```

and have an array of values (skill_ids) `(1,2,3)`.

What is the best way to get all job_ids having all these skill_ids ( ie I want to get 1 and 3 as my result set ).

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having`.  The SQL you want to construct can look like:

```
select job_id
from table t
where skill_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by job_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: "array" has no meaning in the context of MySQL.  Hence, you have an application layer and can construct the appropriate query in that layer.  This is the structure of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ALL

something like:
SELECT job_id FROM table WHERE skill_id = ALL (1,2,3)

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/mysql-any-and-all-subquery-keywords/5533